# Struts 1 Tiles Configuration

Tags: struts, tiles

I'm learning struts 1. Ok, it's working.

And there is something I don't understand with tiles configuration.

On almost every tutorials on the net they say I only have to add the plugin `org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin` in the struts-config.xml.

But it's not working ...  I have to add also the `org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor` controller.

Why? Is there something wrong in my project? I'm using 1.3.10 struts dependencies.

Comment: Did you created also the tiles-defs.xml file? Please, provide you configuration files to make things easier... :-)

Comment: Refer this link: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073902/java-web-development/ui-design-with-tiles-and-struts.html?page=2